# How to use JavaDoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

it's my first time using javadoc. My Problem is, that it just shows me the first method "public static void main" all the other javadoc comments are not shown after creating the doc.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you all!

Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/cia9DprS

And here is my result:
http://www.file-upload.net/download-8938726/doc.zip.html

Greets, progNewFag

Comment: What javadoc command do you use ?

Comment: You did it right; what did you use to create your Javadoc?

Comment: This might be a good question if you included some code (narrow it down to a minimal working example) and your output in your question instead of on external sites. If one of those sites goes down, the question will lose critical information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your methods are private, this is why the default javadoc command will output only your main method (which is the only public method).
In order to output also private methods, use the `-private` option.

Here is the available operators for javadoc about visibility :

- -public                   Show only public classes and members
- -protected                Show protected/public classes and members (default)
- -package                  Show package/protected/public classes and members
- -private                  Show all classes and members